# Concatenate arrays inside array by length

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[ ["01", "Bolognesa", "51"]
, ["01", "Spaghetti", "52"]
, ["01", "Ricardo", "1", "Manjar", "203", "La", "Beriso"]
, ["03", "Miguel", "4", "Manjar", "22", "El", "Beriso"]
]
```

I want to merge them inside the array by length. Like this:

```
[
, [["01", "Bolognesa", "51"],["01", "Spaghetti", "52"]]
, [["01", "Ricardo", "1", "Manjar", "203", "La", "Beriso"],["03", "Miguel", "4", "Manjar", "22", "El", "Beriso"]]
]
```

I tried mapping and filtering:

```
   console.log(mappedText.map(i => i.filter(j => j.length)));
```

but I just can´t crack it. Any ideas?

Comment: please add your tries.

Comment: Look for "group objects by property". Arrays are just objects, and you are interested in their `.length` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array and the length as index for grouping and filter the array with boolean.

```js
var array = [["01", "Bolognesa", "51"], ["01", "Spaghetti", "52"], ["01", "Ricardo", "1", "Manjar", "203", "La", "Beriso"], ["03", "Miguel", "4", "Manjar", "22", "El", "Beriso"]],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            r[a.length] = r[a.length] || [];
            r[a.length].push(a);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! How does this work though? I know you are using reduce with the length as accumulator, but I can´t seem to figure out what it does exactly.

Comment: it takes an array as accumulator and adds an array at the index with the given lengst and pushes the data to it. An because the result is a sparse array, it filters only truthy item.